# Display JSON from file on ESRI JS API

Tags: javascript, esri

I am new to JS API library. I have JSON file in my local folder, I want to read this file and draw as a feature layer with rendering and need to add a pop up on click to display attributes. Please help me to achieve this. I am using code base from  https://github.com/DavidSpriggs/ConfigurableViewerJSAPI

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Simply import the file, the way you do with your scripts:

```
<script type="application/json" src="path to JSON file"></script>
```

The path to the file can be a local path or an URL.

After importing, you can easily access the JSON strings, by just calling their name!
Example:

```
var jStr = points
foreach(i in jStr){
    console.log("Point Nr. "+i +" == X = "+jStr[i].x +", Y = "+jStr[i].y)
}
```

If the JSON file contains:

```
points='[{"x":"580","y":"670"}]';
```

The output will be:

> Point Nr. 0 == X = 580, Y = 670

---

Another method can be using it with JQuery:

```
$.getJSON("path to JSON file", function(jStr) {
    var points = jStr.points
    foreach(i in points){
        console.log("Point Nr. "+i +" == X = "+points[i].x +", Y = "+points[i].y)
    }
});
```